# Visual Studio Code doesn't show Android Studio emulators

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I'm trying to get VS Code to display the dropdown list of available emulators for Flutter development. Currently, when I use the "Flutter: Select Device" or "Flutter: Launch Emulator" commands in VS Code, the emulator options do not appear. No errors nor warnings appear.

I have already created emulators in Android Studio, and they are visible when I run the "flutter emulators" command in the terminal. The "flutter doctor -v" command also shows that everything is set up correctly.

However, when I try to select or launch an emulator within VS Code, the dropdown list does not show the available emulators.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and make the emulator options visible in VS Code.

Thank you for your help!

VS Code version 1.80
Android Studio Flamingo
Flutter 3.10.6
Dart 3.0.6

[image: VSCode settings to link the flutter features]

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.